# What does "Effort of the imagination" mean

Tags: phrases

I found this phrase in *The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes* book;
this is the full paragraph, with my emphasis:

> You will remember that I remarked the other day, just before we went into the very simple problem presented by Miss Mary Sutherland, that for strange effects and extraordinary combinations we must go to life itself, which is always far more daring than any **effort of the imagination.**

Does it mean something like "more daring than we thought"?

Comment: What does it sound like to you? Consult a dictionary for *effort* and *imagination* and you should have your answer.

Comment: It's not a set phrase. The phrase means what the combination of its parts says.

Comment: The form of the sentence is strange so i didn't get it by my first trial to translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He means that, although you can sit and try to resolve bizarre circumstances by imagining possible explanations in your mind, looking for explanations in real life requires more courage, but affords one better answers.